# Secure way to disable copy paste in blogger/website

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste, blogger

I have this Blogspot using blogger,
https://xiaogushiofficial.blogspot.com/2022/10/deliberately-contaminated-chapter-3.html
and I already input javascript to disable right-click and copy-paste ability.

```
    <script language=javascript>
<!--
//Disable right mouse click Script
var message="Function Disabled!";
///////////////////////////////////
function clickIE4(){
if (event.button==2){
alert(message);
return false;}}
function clickNS4(e){
if (document.layers||document.getElementById&&!document.all){
if (e.which==2||e.which==3){
alert(message);
return false;}}}
if (document.layers){
document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEDOWN);
document.onmousedown=clickNS4;}
else if (document.all&&!document.getElementById){
document.onmousedown=clickIE4;
}document.oncontextmenu=new Function("alert(message);return false")
// -->
</script>
```

and also this javascript

```
js'></script><script type='text/javascript'> if(typeof document.onselectstart!="undefined" )
{document.onselectstart=new Function ("return false" ); } else{document.onmousedown=new Function ("return false" );
document.onmouseup=new Function ("return false"); } </script>
```

### Sadly by using the plugin and also disabling javascript, these functions I wrote got disabled pretty easily.

Then I went to this other website,
https://chrysanthemumgarden.com/novel-tl/ks/ks-3/

this website can disable copy-paste and also if you are able to bypass the javascript and copy and paste it, the content will be different. Some random text got pasted.

How to achieve this, anyone has any idea? I want to put this security on my website too, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From what I see, that website is using two things to prevent copy-pasting:

- A [`user-select: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select) style on the container of the text
- The following line of code to prevent copying:

  ```
  $('#novel-content').bind('copy paste cut drag drop', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
  ```

> Some random text got pasted.

Due to `.preventDefault`, nothing will be copied - what will be on your clipboard will remain whatever it was before you tried to copy.

If you remove those two through the browser's developer tools, there's no further barrier to copying the text.

If you wanted to implement it yourself, all you need to do is those two steps above - `user-select: none` on the container, plus a `copy` event listener that unconditionally calls `preventDefault` on the event.

That said, there's no foolproof way to completely stop the user from copying text on your site. Ultimately, if you send text to the client's machine, the client will be able to do whatever they want with it, and will be able to bypass whatever protection mechanisms you have if they're determined enough. You could send an image instead, but OCR tools exist as well.

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, but where to put those code? in the javascript, it doesnt function. sorry, im still new to coding.

Comment: Put `user-select: none` as a CSS rule on an element for which you want to prevent text selection inside of. Put the JavaScript into a `<script>` tag, with the selector replaced with whatever selector you want to prevent copying from.